# Adding values to a listbox in zkoss using java

Tags: java, zk

I need to add values to a listbox in zkoss using java - I mean dynamic values.

I have an zul like this

```
<window id="win_1" use="com.test.tets">
    <listbox id="a">
        <listhead>
            <listheader label="Name"   />
            <listheader label="Age"   />
            <listheader label="Sex"   />
        </listhead>
        <listitem id="i">        
        </listitem>
    </listbox>
</window>
```

I need to add values from mysql db to this listbox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Listmodel to do so, please refer to this article - [Using a ListModel adn ListitemRenderer](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials/Displaying_information_using_the_Listbox/Using_a_ListModel_and_ListitemRenderer)

Answer (score 0):

you can use listmodel list, example :

```
    yourListBox.setModel(new ListModelList<BeanClass>(beanDao.findAll()));
    yourListBox.setItemRenderer(new ListItemRenderer<BeanClass>) {

        @Override
        public void render(Listitem item, BeanClass data, int index) throws Exception {
            Listcell cell = new Listcell();
            cell.appendChild(new Label(data.getFoo()));
            item.appendChild(cell);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

MVVM Approach

your zul file

```
   <window id="win_1" use="com.test.tets"
    apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('your view model class')">
        <listbox id="a" model="@load(vm.listModel)">
            <listhead>
                <listheader label="Name"   />
                <listheader label="Age"   />
                <listheader label="Sex"   />
            </listhead>
            <template name="model">
              <listitem>
                  components that will represent a row in listbox...
              </listitem> 
           </template>
        </listbox>
    </window>
```

your view model

```
public class SampleViewModel
{

     private ListModelList<class that respresent row> listModel;

     @Init
     public void init()
     {
        init your model here.... 
     }

     public ListModelList<class that respresent row> getListModel{
         return this.listMode;
     }

     public void setListModel(ListModelList<class that respresent row> listModel)
     {
         this.listModel=listModel;
     }
}
```

The list model list will also take care of notification of changes in view model.